# How can I manipulate the DOM after my directive's content has been loaded on the page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing my own chat interface, to help me better understand angularJs and socket.io.

My chat window is fixed, with overflow set to auto. I am using the following directive to manipulate the DOM to scroll, so that as each message is pushed onto the model array, it will be visible at the bottom of the window.

```
app.directive('plnkScroll', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              angular.element(element)[0].scrollIntoView();
        }
    };
}]);
```

In theory, this works. However, if the message is long enough to take up more than one line, it does not scroll so that the entire line is clearly visible.

This is because the `scrollIntoView` method is being executed on the DOM while the angular expression has yet to be evaluated (in this case, `{{item.text}}`)

Is it possible to execute this function *after* the Angular expression has been evaluated and the model data has been injected into the DOM?

here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xisnx5MBUKLAxGFA89Q9), to help illustrate what I am doing.

p.s. using jQuery is not an option for me, I would like to do things "the angular way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your can use $timeout excute your code after directive element append to parent.

```
app.directive('plnkScroll', ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              $timeout(function(){
                angular.element(element)[0].scrollIntoView();
              },50);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: is there any other solution other than adding a timeout ?

Answer (score 2):

To extend Kain's response, it actually works without specifying an arbitrary number of milliseconds for the timeout. [Simply allowing a digest cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066239/defer-angularjs-watch-execution-after-digest-raising-dom-event) to occur via the `$timeout` is sufficient. You can do this by omitting the second argument to the `$timeout` function, [which defaults to zero](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout).

Alternatively, if you wanted the scroll to occur based on a scope variable changing, you could specify an attribute to the directive to watch using `scope.$watch` and scroll when the watch fires.