# Angular JS identify an digest complete event and removing # from url in angular js during viewchange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kineticjs

1) Is there any digest complete event which I can use to update my canvas. I have an angular app which has view for different properties of the canvas object. Whenever I change the property, once the digest is complete, If I can get the digest complete event I can update the canvas(using kineticJs) to redraw the chart with latest properties.

[image: Popup view and Canvas]

Currently i am calling a method from the view

[image]

2) I am just using views and routing it to a new view whenever an object settings is opened. In this case the url also change with the webpage/#view.Its just the popup I dont need the #view at the end of the page but to still use the routing and view concept. Is there any otherway.

Comment: Is just watching the properties not good enough?

Comment: I can imagine that you want this for performance reasons, eg only redraw when everything has settled down.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Update

Karl seamon gave a talk in [ng-conf 2014](http://ng-conf.org/).

In this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y) (**22:20 minute**) he talked about a future possiblity of a built-in **$postDigestWatch**.

Here is an open issue in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5828

So, It will probably get to the core in future releases, until then you can use the trick below.

---

#### An [example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbkKWIJVxGCAipQdFRzf?p=preview).

- A digest cycle may have multiple `$digest`.
- I `$watch` for the first `$digest` to register a `$timeout` which would run after the digest cycle ends.
- I must unregister the `$watch` immediately to avoid multiple `$timeout` callbacks for one digest cycle.
- In the `$timeout` callback I invoke the **user callback** and register a `$watch` for the next `$digest`.

#### Use $watch in conjunction with $timeout:

```
function postDigest(callback){    
  var unregister = $rootScope.$watch(function(){  
    unregister();
    $timeout(function(){
      callback();
      postDigest(callback);
    },0,false);       
  });
}

postDigest(function(){
  console.log('do something');
})
```

---

**$digest** ,From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope):

> If you want to be notified whenever **$digest()** is called, you can register a watchExpression function with **$watch()** with no listener.

**$timeout** , From here: [Defer angularjs watch execution after $digest (raising DOM event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066239/defer-angularjs-watch-execution-after-digest-raising-dom-event)

> $timeout will cause another digest cycle to be executed after the function is executed. If your trigger does not affect anything Angular, you can set the invokeApply argument to false to avoid running another digest cycle.

Comment: That will call the provided function on every digest. It does not inform you if a digest has been completed.

Comment: I updated the answer so it will only run once after a digest cycle

Comment: If the current digest triggers another digest (eg changes a value on any scope) the postDigest is called every time (not when the digest has settled).

Comment: The $timeout callback is invoked **only once** after a digest cycle therefore postDigest would be called **only once after a digest cycle**.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to what Ilan said, you could use $evalAsync.

from the same [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync):

```
Executes the expression on the current scope at a later point in time.

The $evalAsync makes no guarantees as to when the expression will be executed, only that:

it will execute after the function that scheduled the evaluation (preferably before DOM rendering).
at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution.
Any exceptions from the execution of the expression are forwarded to the $exceptionHandler service.

Note: if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled. However, it is encouraged to always call code that changes the model from within an $apply call. That includes code evaluated via $evalAsync
```

Also, take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734#issuecomment-3657272) in regards to this