# AngularJS "cron jobs" - run action on every $digest

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to execute some function on every `$digest` cycle.

The documentation for `$scope` reads:

> If you want to be notified whenever $digest is called, you can
>   register a watchExpression function with no listener. (Since
>   watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest cycle when a
>   change is detected, be prepared for multiple calls to your listener.)

So does that mean it can be accomplished this way:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
  // Cron job
});
```

I'm not sure if every `$digest` cycle hits the `$rootScope`, or is it even emitted from `$rootScope`. I only know there's only 1 `$digest` loop and it occurs every time a $watch detects changes.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138388/angular-js-identify-an-digest-complete-event-and-removing-from-url-in-angular/21138524#21138524

Comment: @IlanFrumer saw it, and one-upped you as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: So does that mean it can be accomplished this way?

A: **Yes**, although some directives/services might choose to only digest their local scope to improve performance.

That said it's recommended to execute as less code as possible in a digest loop.

digest isn't like a cron job, it doesn't run automatically every x seconds.
It runs when you call $scope.$apply() or when an event like ng-click or $http.get occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. You got me curious as well - what is the difference between digesting a local scope and the opposite?

Comment: You call $scope.$digest when you're sure that only that $scope or its childscopes have changed. This limits the dirty-checking compared to $scope.$apply which dirty-checks all $scopes and additionally $eval()s the argument.