# Prevent button click while digest cycle is running in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am updating the $scope on a button click which basically makes a Restangular call, fetches data and populates the $scope variable.

However, if the user clicks the button multiple times while a $digest cycle is running, the $scope gets updated with duplicated values.

I am pretty sure it's a common problem. However, I haven't come across one on SO with a solution I am looking for.

People have suggested using `$timeout` but it seems anti-logic.

I'd rather just disable the button while the `$digest` cycle is running.

Here's what I've implemented so far.

```
$scope.names = [];
$scope.disableButton = true;
FetchNames.getAllNames().then(function(result){
  result.data.forEach(function(name){
    $scope.names.push(name);
  });
$scope.disableButton = false;
});
```

Here, the button is disabled while the promise is getting resolved.
But that doesn't solve my problem. I need to check when the digest cycle is completed.

Comment: This will be useful for you i think so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138388/angular-js-identify-an-digest-complete-event-and-removing-from-url-in-angular

Comment: I do not see why the `$timeout` whould be "anti-logic" as it waits for the digest cycle to finish before it fires the callback.

Comment: cbass, wouldn't it run the digest cycle again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use ng-disabled built-in directive to disable button when user click it. to achieve this just set a variable to true. Look at the code below

```
<button ng-click="btn1=true, yourFunction()" ng-disabled='btn1'>
```

which in your controller can be like this

```
    $scope.btn1= false;
    $scope.yourFunction= function(){
      $scope.names = [];
      FetchNames.getAllNames().then(function(result){
        result.data.forEach(function(name){
          $scope.names.push(name);
       });
       $scope.disableButton = false;
     };
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of digest cycle being initiated again.

Comment: I found this [link](https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/) useful for your digest cycle.
 Hope it will work out for you!

Comment: can you please remove the down vote and up vote, if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.names = [];
$scope.disableButton = true;
FetchNames.getAllNames().then(function(result){
  // if in digest; reuturn
  if($scope.$$phase || $scope.$root.$$phase ){return}
  result.data.forEach(function(name){
    $scope.names.push(name);
  });
$scope.disableButton = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

[Angular JS identify an digest complete event and removing # from url in angular js during viewchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138388/angular-js-identify-an-digest-complete-event-and-removing-from-url-in-angular)

and this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)